# rails app with a login via google+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-plus

Is it oauth I am thinking of when I see apps even like stack overflow let you login via google.  I want a rails app that doesn't require all this fancy sign up but to have users that bind uniquely to data in the app. Just not sure the terminology I am looking for.   Basically an app that once you log in using Google knows you've "logged in"  and can store work done in the rails page to your account id.  I saw something like this:
https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2

I think this is what I want.  Basically log into app with an account you have or set up somewhere else just so I know you are an unique user and can bind data to you.

Comment: Yes, "Google+ Sign-In" is just OAuth2 (with a particular login scope that indicates access to Google+ profile information). There is also a more general "Google Sign-In" for signing in with a Google account (regardless of whether that account has Google+ enabled or not).

Comment: Great thanks Michael seems like the general one is what I want.  Guessing a simple oauth2 gem would do it